# How to auto-populate sub-field selects from within a parent field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, auto-populate

I'm using the [ACF tutorial here to build from.](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/)
What I'd like to do is use the values in a text sub-field to populate other select sub-fields within the same repeater field. I know it sounds recursive and maybe that's prohibitive. The field admin will not be to ajax-y or update on the fly, it's more of an admin field for other site functionality.

Anyway, here's what I have so far.

- ACF Repeater field = core_values
- Page the field is on = valuesadmin
- Source text sub-field within core_values = value_name
- Target sub-fields (
  each needing dynamically propagated selects from value_name) =

  - constructor1_name
  - constructor2_name
  - constructor3_name
  - destructor1_name
  - destructor2_name

I've tried to modify the code at the tutorial linked above and put it in the theme's functions.php and in the main file of a plugin I'm building other custom functions.

```
/**
* ACF population functions
*/

function acf_load_core_values_field_choices( $field ) {

// reset choices
$field['choices'] = array();


// if has rows
if( have_rows('core_values', 'valuesadmin') ) {

    // while has rows
    while( have_rows('core_values', 'valuesadmin') ) {

        // instantiate row
        the_row();


        // vars
        $value = get_sub_field('value_name');
        $label = get_sub_field('value_name');


        // append to choices
        $field['constructor1_name'][ $value ] = $label;
        $field['constructor2_name'][ $value ] = $label;
        $field['constructor3_name'][ $value ] = $label;
        $field['destructor1_name'][ $value ] = $label;
        $field['destructor2_name'][ $value ] = $label;

    }

}


// return the field
   return $field;

}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=constructor1_name',    'acf_load_core_values_field_choices');
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=constructor2_name',   'acf_load_core_values_field_choices');
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=constructor3_name', 'acf_load_core_values_field_choices');
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=destructor1_name', 'acf_load_core_values_field_choices');
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=destructor2_name', 'acf_load_core_values_field_choices');
```

Obviously this isn't propagating the select sub-fields as I'd like.

Questions:
 - Is this even possible ( the value_name fields are all filled with values already ) 
 - Where should the function code go?
 - Maybe I've mangled the code somehow

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try to use someting else than Wordpress :-). But if the WP-Plugin has not a buildin-function which helps you to load options filtered by a previosly chosen value, than you should try to use javascript. Or the jquery.ajax function: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I achieved the functionality I was looking for by first moving this all to an ACF options page and then creating another ACF field ( values_master) with which I could populate the values dynamically in a second field on the options page. So I'm not sure if this was not working because of some recursively but it IS working.

```
function acf_load_value_field_choices( $field ) {

    // reset choices
    $field['choices'] = array();


    // if has rows
    if( have_rows('values_master', 'option') ) {

        // while has rows
        while( have_rows('values_master', 'option') ) {

            // instantiate row
            the_row();


            // vars
            $value = get_sub_field('value_name');
            $label = get_sub_field('value_name');


            // append to choices
            $field['choices'][ $value ] = $label;

        }

    }


    // return the field
    return $field;

}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=constructor1_name', 'acf_load_value_field_choices');
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=constructor2_name', 'acf_load_value_field_choices');
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=constructor3_name', 'acf_load_value_field_choices');
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=destructor1_name', 'acf_load_value_field_choices');
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=destructor2_name', 'acf_load_value_field_choices');
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=value_mstr_name', 'acf_load_value_field_choices');
```